# Выделение оборотов с "таких как"

Tags: пунктуация

Если в предложении идет сравнительный оборот, начинающийся словами "таких как", но после однородных членов предложение продолжается словами и т. п. или и др., то нужно ли ставить запятую после этих однородных членов, т. е. закрывать оборот?

...для всех важных УФ элементов, таких как С, Р, S, N, Sn, As, В, и т. п.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ...после однородных членов предложение
> продолжается словами и т. п. или и
> др., то **нужно ли ставить запятую** после
> этих однородных членов, т. е.
> закрывать оборот?
>
> ...для всех важных УФ элементов, таких
> как С, Р, S, N, Sn, As, В, и т. п.

НЕ НУЖНО. Запятая перед ***и т. п.*** не ставится. Плюс я бы поставил дефис между ***УФ*** и ***элементов***.

Правильно: *...для всех важных УФ-элементов, таких как С, Р, S, N, Sn, As, В и т. п*.

Comment: А если предложение построено так: в нем будут участвовать представители таких компаний, как... далее идет перечисление... и многие другие?

Comment: Всё зависит от того,  отличаются ли чем-либо "такие компании, как…" от "многих других". 

Давайте попробуем заменить "такие компании" и "многие другие" их названиями, пусть даже условными: 

"такие" -- А, Б, С;

"многие другие" -- В, Г, Д...

Если Вы сможете написать 

"…в нем будут участвовать представители таких компаний, как А, Б, С, В, Г, Д…",

 то запятая перед "и многие другие" в Вашем предложении не будет нужна:

"…в нем будут участвовать представители таких компаний, как А, Б и многие другие".

Comment: В противном случае запятая перед "и многие другие" нужна. Я бы при таком понимании "многих других" постарался бы как-то перестроить исходное предложение.  К примеру, так:  

"…в нем будут участвовать представители таких компаний, как А, Б и С,  а также представители  многих других компаний".

Answer (score 2):

Да, оборот закрывается.

В сравнительный оборот могут входить  составные союзы ТАК ЖЕ КАК,  ТАК ЖЕ КАК И,  а также союзные выражения ТАКОЙ ЖЕ КАК, ТАКОЙ КАК, ТАКОЙ ЖЕ КАК И:

Наша группа, так же как и параллельная, сдала все зачеты.