# Оборот "такой как" при отсутствии однородных членов предложения

Tags: пунктуация

Верно ли стоят запятые при обороте "такую как":

**Также можно заметить использованную стилистическую фигуру, такую, как инверсия.**

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Выделение оборотов с "таких как"](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/50261/%d0%92%d1%8b%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%80%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2-%d1%81-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b8%d1%85-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba)

Answer (score 3):

**Также можно заметить использованную стилистическую фигуру, такую как инверсия.**

Но лучше так: **Также можно отметить использование такой стилистической фигуры, как инверсия.**

Возможны **два варианта для этой конструкции:** (1) такая фигура, как инверсия;  (2) фигура, такая как инверсия.